# URL Rewrite: From category to CMS Page

Tags: magento-1.9, category, url-rewrite, cms-pages

I've created a CMS Page.

```
URL Key = about/page1.
```

I've created some Categories. One of them, category #1, it's called about.

```
URL Key = about
```

and its first subcategory, category #2, is named Page

```
URL Key = page1.
```

I want both categories to redirect to about/page1 CMS page.

My understanding is that I'll have a system rewrite:

```
from category/1 to catalog/category/view/id/1  and 
from category/2 to catalog/category/view/id/2.
```

What URL Rewrites I'd need to add for redirecting both categories to my CMS Page? So if I click on both category links, the page about/page1 is opened?

Comment: https://github.com/Mestrona/Mestrona_CategoryRedirect

Answer (score 0):

Follow these step for url rewrite:

1. Find Magento URL Rewrite Management - by going to Catalog > Rewrite Management
2. Select Add URL Rewrite
3. Select the custom option from the drop down
4. Now you will see few options:

**ID Path:** Is the unique identifier for this rewrite. This should just be custom, but is only used for admin purposes

**Request Path:** Is the URL you would like to redirect

**Target Path:** Is the URL you would like the Request Path directed to

**Redirect:** You always want this to be permanent as 302 (or temporary redirects) do not pass any of the link juice to the new URL.

**Description:** This is an optional description field. Use this to keep notes on what and why you set this URL redirect up

Fill these fields out correctly

**Click Save**- This should be the job done.

Quickly try out your redirect to make sure it’s working correctly

Comment: Could you pls help  @ https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/210130/57334\

Answer (score 0):

Why not simplify your setup and instead of having 3 separate entities, reduce it 2.

Copy all of your `CMS Page` content into a `Static Block` and give it a name & identifier.

Take Category #1 and change it's `Display Settings` to the following:

> Display Mode - Static Block Only
>
> CMS Block - Choose your new block with CMS Page contents

Now you have your `About` page contents in a category, and you can setup one redirect/rewrite from Category #2 to this Category #1

There's also the handy (but sloppy) layout update with JS you can use:

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="SOME.BLOCK.NAME.HERE">
        <action method="setText">
            <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">location.replace("https://www.WEBSITE.com/CUSTOM-REDIRECT");</script>]]></text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

If you choose to, you can update the `Custom Design` category tab's `Page Layout` to `1 column` if you don't want to show left or right sidebars. The JS redirect isn't clean can cause a slight delay when loading, so your `URL rewrite` is probably still the best option.